# How to go from T(n-1)+cn, to T(n)=O(n^2)?

Tags: big-o

How did my teacher go from T(n-1)+cn, to T(n)=O(n^2)

Am I multiplying out T(n) * n? Little confused on how he got there without doing any work in class.

Comment: Use the Mathematics exchange to ask these sorts of questions. Much more appropriate.

Comment: But it's big-o related is is not? 0_o

Comment: I mean, sure, big o notation relates to algorithms... But at its heart, this is a complexity-class issue which is mathematical in nature. Especially since you're deriving something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have more luck expanding this out using the iteration method:

> T(n) = T(n - 1) + cn
>
> = T(n - 2) + c(n-1) + cn
>
> = T(n - 3) + c(n-2) + c(n-1) + cn
>
> ...
>
> = T(1) + 1c + 2c + 3c + ... + c(n-1) + cn
>
> = O(1) + c(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + (n-1) + n)

That last summation is O(n<sup>2</sup>) because it's the sum of the first n integers. Therefore, the whole summation works out to O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Hope this helps!